# Google chrome finds image to be insecure on an SSL connection, but it is valid?

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, https

For some reason, Google Chrome finds my logo to be insecure even though it is uploaded within the SSL-secured subdomain.

https://clients.mybbwebhost.com/logo.png

Chrome is giving me the error:

> Your connection to domainname is encrypted with 256-bit encryption. However, this page includes other resources which are not secure. These resources can be viewed by others while in transit, and can be modified by an attacker to change the look of the page. The connection uses TLS 1.0. The connection is encrypted using AES_256_CBC, with SHA1 for message authentication and DHE_RSA as the key exchange mechanism.

The result is that any page that has this image is deemed insecure.  Note that Internet Explorer does not give any security warnings.

What can I do to stop this warning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clear your cache, doesn't show any warnings to me.